# How can I tell if an object is a Mockito mock?

Tags: java, mockito

Is it possible to tell in code if a given object is a Mockito mock or not?

The reason I'd like to do this is to return a different error message when a mock is being used. This would be used to suggest to other developers that they should use a pre-prepared mock that is already set to answer calls in a useful way rather than creating the mock themselves.

At the moment the best I have is `object.getClass().getName().contains("EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB")` but this feels hacky.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As a follow up, the Mockito public API now has [this method](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mockingDetails-java.lang.Object-):

```
MockingDetails org.mockito.Mockito.mockingDetails(Object toInspect)
```

Which is the result of the issue that @David Wallace raised. The returned object supports the methods `isMock()` as well as `isSpy()` along with a few other methods that provide additional mocking information.

#### Example:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockingDetails; 
assertThat(mockingDetails(probablyAMockedObject).isMock()).isTrue();
```

Answer (score 71):

Looks like there is no such API (please raise an issue, it should be!) Fortunately (following your comment below) there is a method in the `org.mockito.internal.util` package:

```
import org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil;

new MockUtil().isMock(obj)
```

In the future `Mockito.isMock()` method might be added to public API, see: [Issue 313: Provide isMock outside of org.mockito.internal)](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=313).

Comment: Following on from your answer I took a look at the [source for MockUtil](https://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/mockito/trunk/src/org/mockito/internal/util/MockUtil.java?r=2020) and directly under the private `isMockitoMock` method there is a public `isMock` method that it seems can be used. I will post on the Mockito mailing list to check if it is a good idea to be calling methods from `org.mockito.internal.util` ourselves.

Comment: One of the intentions of the `org.mockito.internal.util` package is that the Mockito team could conceivably change anything in this package, in a newer version.  So if you use this package, your tests could conceivably break in the future.  However, it's extremely unlikely that we'd get rid of this particular method, so I'd say it's fairly safe to use.

Comment: @mikej: +1, somehow I missed that one, thanks! I removed the old answer and put your suggestion instead so it better stands out. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: OK, I've raised an issue on the Mockito issues register, to get `isMock()` added to the main Mockito class (that is, not internal).  Unless someone else in the Mockito team objects, I will add this in the next release of Mockito.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWallace - I've found [the issue that you've raised](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=313) - I'll use the method through `MockUtil` for now but will update our code as and when the method becomes available on the main `Mockito` class. Thanks to @Tomasz as well.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I added link to issue 313, will fix answer once this issue is solved.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz, isMock has been added to the api.
`import org.mockito.Mockito.*`
`mockingDetails(obj).isMock()`