# How do I know if Mock in Spring boot is being used or not?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am testing a service class which uses a Dao layer under it.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class AppServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private AppService appService;

    private AppConfig appConfig = new AppConfig(), appConfigOut = new AppConfig();

    @MockBean //This statement is under inspection in the problem
    private AppDao appDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       String appKey = "jsadf87bdfys78fsd6f0s7f8as6sd";
       appConfig.setAppKey(appKey);

       appConfigOut.setAppKey(appKey);


       appConfigOut.setRequestPerMinute(null);
       appConfigOut.setRequestDate(DateTime.now());
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFetchAppConfigValidParam() throws Exception {
        when(appDao.fetchAppConfig(appConfig)).thenReturn(appConfigOut);
        assertThat(appService.fetchAppConfig(appConfig)).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(appConfigOut);
    }
```

In the above program when I write `@MockBean`, the test throws a NullPointerException, but when I write `@Mock` the test executes successfully. I think the appDao being called is the actual one defined in `appService` and accessing the database. This is because the time taken by the test is around 200ms and usual test cases for other applications is 60ms-100ms. But I am not sure because other cases where DAO really access data takes 400ms to 500ms.

How do I know mock is actually working and when `appService` calls the `appDao` method from inside it is actually the mock. Is there any programmatical way to verify this.

P.S. If `@Mock` works in this scenario what is `@MockBean` is useful for in spring boot.

Comment: The problem is your code. Remove `@InjectMocks` and `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` from your test. When using `@MockBean` Spring Boot takes care of all that for you... You are basically fighting that with your current setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum It has worked for me. Thanks. But, what if I use both MockBean and Mock, how should I use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in the scenario.

Comment: You shouldn't do that use either one but don't mix as that will lead you to issues. Also if you are going to replace variables in bean instances yourself you would also have to refresh the application context after the test.

Comment: What if I don't want to mock a bean. Here is a question which describes the situation. [Mock and MockBean] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833049/mocking-a-containerrequestfilter-of-jersey-in-a-spring-boot-application)

Comment: @M.Deinum What is the solution for the above mentioned issue?

Comment: Don't use annotations... Just use `Mockito.mock` and really ask yourself if what you are doing should something you should be doing. Do you really need that test to be a spring integration test if you are mocking a filter? Shouldn't it rather be a simple unit test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138226/discussion-between-tarun-maganti-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M.Deinum is pointing you in the correct direction in the comment.

Maybe you want to give the spring documentation about Mocking and Spying in tests a read - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

But to answer you question - you can use `MockingDetails` to tell if an object is a mock.

```
MockingDetails mockingDetails = org.mockito.Mockito.mockingDetails(appDao)

boolean appDaoIsMock = mockingDetails.isMock()
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138628/5371736)